# Why is Jupiter's ring system so faint?

Tags: planets, solar-system, jupiter

Planetary ring systems are formed when asteroids, comets, or any other large objects pass too close to the planet and are torn apart by the planet's gravity [1]. Jupiter is often called the "punching bag" of our solar system. Because of it's massive gravity, it is impacted more often by asteroids and other objects [2].

So I would expect Jupiter to have a more prominent ring system than Saturn. Why is Jupiter's ring system not as spectacular as Saturn's?

---

[1] https://www.physlink.com/education/askexperts/ae188.cfm

[2] https://www.space.com/32420-jupiter-asteroid-impact-rate.html

Answer (score 2):

> So I would expect Jupiter to have a more prominent ring system than Saturn. Why is Jupiter's ring system not as spectacular as Saturn's?

The [rings of Jupiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rings_of_Jupiter) likely formed due to very different processes than that of [Saturn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn).  It is thought that Saturn's rings formed from the collapse of a large, icy body (e.g., something like half the size of [Enceladus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enceladus)).

Jupiter's rings form from debris resulting from meteoroid impacts on the [moons of Jupiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moons_of_Jupiter).  Much of this debris is then swept up by the Jovian moons or Jupiter itself.  Because the rings are made of rocky/dirty dust, they do not reflect a lot of light like Saturn's rings, which are largely made of icy rock.